# Why doesn't multiprocessing.Pool increase computational speed linearly?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to understand parallel programming better in Python and can't understand why increase in number of processes does not decrease **time of program execution linearly**?

For instance using 4 processes program takes 10.8 sec to complete, using 8 processes 7.280761957168579 sec, instead **of expected 5.4-6 seconds**. I understand that starting a process takes about 0.1 seconds, but the numbers still don't add up, it should **be maximum 6.5 seconds with 8 processes, not** 7.280761957168579...

Can someone explain, why time decrease is not linear?

My simple program:

```
def sum_square_with_mp(numbers):

    start_time = time.time()
    p = Pool(8)
    result = p.map(sum_square, numbers)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    end_time = time.time() - start_time

    print(f"Processing {len(numbers)} numbers took {end_time} time using multiprocessing.")

def sum_square(number):
    s = 0
    for i in range(number):
        s += i * i
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = range(20000)
    sum_square_with_mp(numbers)
```

Comment: In a word, **overhead**.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's much more overhead than just starting up sub-processes, ie creating the pool, mapping function calls, serializing params, monitoring execution, retrieving and unserializing results etc.

Then, you can AT MOST have one process executed by one given core at a given time - so if you have 4 cores, at most 4 process are really actively executing simultaneously.

And finally, process execution is handled by your OS, which will decide which process is currently active on which core, dependings on some rather complex rules and heuristics. Most of the time, a process execution will be interrupted and resumed quite a few times before it (eventually) completes, so the "real" execution time (the one between when the process is launched and when it completes) is actually not the same as the time spent effectively executing this process. Oh and yes, this context switching does have some overhead too...

Note that this is nothing Python specific, it's just plain [OS process scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) - CS101, really.

Answer (score 0):

the parent/driving process needs to serialise the values from the range before sending them to the child/worker processes.  this takes some time, as does unserializing the results that come back.  this adds to the "non-parallelizable" portion of the code.  see [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) for more info

you've also not said how many CPUs/cores your system has nor how they're being occupied, which will also have an effect on this